# A surjective continuous mapping between $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $p: X\rightarrow Y$ a continuous surjective and closed map such that $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact for every $y\in Y$. Prove that
>   If $X$ is Hausdorff (regular) then $Y$ is Hausdorff (regular).

Can anyone give me hint to attack this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I begin trying to prove the condition to be a Hausdorff, let $x,y\in Y$ distinct points. The sets $p^{-1}(x), p^{-1}(y)$ are compact set... what can I do with this property?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** assume $y_1\ne y_2$ and look for disjoint neighborhoods of them. 
Pick pairs $x_1,x_2$ from $X$ *in all possible ways* such that $p(x_1)=y_1$ and $p(x_2)=y_2$, together with their disjoint neighborhoods.

> Since $p$ is surjective and a closed map, it is also open. 
>  Take the union of neighborhoods of the $x_1$ 's and the union of those of the
>  $x_2$ 's, because of compactness, only finitely many of them are enough to cover the fiber $p^{-1}(y_1)$ [and $p^{-1}(y_2)$, resp.]...

Comment: What in the regular case?

Comment: The regular case is similar..

Comment: A surjective open map is not necessarily a closed map, and likewise a surjective closed map is not necessarily an open map
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps#Properties